# let definitions visible after error in gambit's gsi?

Tags: scheme, gambit

While experimenting with gambit's gsi (4.6.6), I ran into an odd situation when I typed in something invalid inside let.

Doing it the normal way, everything is as expected. `i and`j are not visible.

```
> (let ((i 4) (j 3)) (display (+ i j)) (newline))
7
> i
*** ERROR IN (console)@2.1 -- Unbound variable: i
1> j
*** ERROR IN (console)@3.1 -- Unbound variable: j
```

However, if I flub up in the let block, `i and`j are visible. It's almost as if I'm still inside the scope of the let form. Is that what's going on? Also, looking at the numbers on the prompt e.g. `>`1> `2> etc. It looks like there's information there as well. If so, what is that? Maybe something related to nesting or an error mode?

```
2> (let ((i 2) (j 3)) (display + i j) (newline))
*** ERROR IN (console)@4.20 -- Wrong number of arguments passed to procedure
(display '#<procedure #2 +> 2 3)
3> i
2
3> j
3
```

This is a little different than in clojure. e.g.

```
user=> (defn display [n] (print n))
#'user/one-arg-function
user=> (let [i 2 j 3] (display + i j) (println))
ArityException Wrong number of args (3) passed to: user$one-arg-function clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:437)

user=> i 
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: i in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0) 

user=> j
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: j in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0)
```

Comment: I restarted the interpreter before generating the sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature of Gambit's interactive debugger.

From the manual: http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~gambit/doc/gambit-c.html#Debugging

> A nested REPL is then initiated in the context of the point of
>   execution where the evaluation was stopped. The nested REPL’s
>   continuation and evaluation environment are the same as the point
>   where the evaluation was stopped. For example when evaluating the
>   expression ‘(let ((y (- 1 1))) (* (/ x y) 2))’, a “divide by zero”
>   error is reported and the nested REPL’s continuation is the one that
>   takes the result and multiplies it by two. The REPL’s lexical
>   environment includes the lexical variable ‘y’. This allows the
>   inspection of the evaluation context (i.e. the lexical and dynamic
>   environments and continuation), which is particularly useful to
>   determine the exact location and cause of an error.

In your case, the nested REPL started inside the `let` and thus had `i` and `j` bound.

Comment: +1 "Don't call it a bug, call it a feature" :) . Just kidding, it makes sense for debugging purposes.